# How to set Request headers for unit-testing in aspnet core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, xunit.net

> Using: NETCore.App 1.1, xunit 2.2.0-beta4-build3444, Moq 4.6.38-alpha.

I am trying to test an ASP.Net Core controller that needs a header called "X-ClientID" to be present in the request.
I have now written my test function as follows:

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    var controller = new GraphController(this.positiveAuthorizer, this.loggerFactory, this.elasticsearchSettings);

    controller.Request.Headers.Add("X-ClientID", "1234");

    var result = controller.Get("calls", "year", "day", "1", "sliding", new DateTime(2016, 11, 1)).Result;

    // TODO: Write assert statements on result
}
```

`positiveAuthorizer`, `loggerFactory`and `elasticsearchSettings` are mocked classes using Moq, which are working as expected inside the controller.

But `controller.Request` is `null`. Also, `controller.Request` is get-only, so I cannot set it to a new value.

How can I set the X-Client header before calling my controller?

Comment: An alternative is to write an integration test that spins up a test server and sends an actual HTTP request to the controller. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but it still feels like it should be possible to just test the code, but hey, at least now I can also test the actual json encoding/decoding in one go.

Comment: I think this was allready solved by -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400030/mock-httpcontext-for-unit-testing-a-net-core-mvc-controller