# Test Web API controller when using Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am interested in testing a specific call that is being made to the web api, to make sure it does what i am expecting it to do. In the controller I'm searching for some info based on the user id that is currently logged in (the authorization is being handled by the Identity Server). When that test is being run I want to already have an user that is authenticated and logged in. How can I mock/bypass the whole authorization process made by Identity?

Answer (score 0):

When you setup the authentication handler correctly in your web api project, the claims from the access token are populated into the User object of the HttpContext:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://<youridentityserver>";
    options.Audience = "yourapi";
    options.SaveToken = true;
});
```

```csharp
public async Task<ActionResult> Get(string userName)
{
    //Does the subject claim match the user name?
    var subject = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    if ((subject == null) || (subject.Value != userName))
    return Unauthorized();

}
```

By mocking the HttpContext in a unit test, you can inspect the User object in your controller method.
How to mock HttpContext:

[Mock HttpContext for unit testing a .NET core MVC controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400030/mock-httpcontext-for-unit-testing-a-net-core-mvc-controller)