# C# - Set URL of request of controller for unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, controller, nunit-3.0, fakeiteasy

I am writing a unit test where I need to set the URL of the incoming request in order evaluate the URL inside the controller's method.  I am using FakeItEasy and NUnit3.

Here is the code under test and the relevant part:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
{
...
   var queryString = Uri.UnescapeDataString(Request.Query["returnUrl"]);
...
}
```

I want to set queryString to a value I specify in my unit test.  Can someone help me with example code?  The system under test is the controller.  I can only seem to find Moq related code. Seems simple enough.

Comment: I suppose you could set the required value of the Request Query through an HttpContext. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400030/mock-httpcontext-for-unit-testing-a-net-core-mvc-controller) question & answer might be just what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could just bind a parameter to the query string like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel, [FromQuery] string returnUrl)
{
}
```

And in your test, call the `Login` method with the value you want for `returnUrl`

Answer (score -2):

No need to user FakeItEasy or NUnit to solve this.  Here is the line of code that solved my issue:

```
_accountController.Request.QueryString = new QueryString("?returnUrl=value");
```

Replaced 'param=value' with what was needed to test it.