# object reference not set to instance of an object issues in unit testing of asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, model-view-controller

I am the beginner of writing unit tests for asp.net. I created a simple project and try to start my testing journey. However, I met two errors with the same issue:"object reference not set to instance of an object" The first place is in the home controller as below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    } 

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
```

Here is my test method:

```
public class HomeControllerUnitTests
{
     ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

     [Fact]
     public void Error_ActionExecutes_ReturnsAViewResult()
     {
        // Arrange
        var homeController = new HomeController(_logger);

        // Act
        var result = homeController.Error() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.Null(result.ViewData.Model);
     }
}
```

The second place is in the Movie Controller:

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
        private readonly MvcMovieContext _context;

        public MoviesController(MvcMovieContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Movies
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Movie.ToListAsync());
        }
}
```

My test method is as below:

```
public class MoviesControllerUnitTests
{
        private Mock<MvcMovieContext> _mock;

        [Fact]
        public async Task Index_ActionExecutes_ReturnsAViewResult()
        {
            // Arrange
            MoviesController controller = new MoviesController(_mock.Object);

            // Act
            var result = await controller.Index() as Task<ViewResult>;

            // Assert
            Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
        }
    }
```

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` line there should be an indication about which file and line the error occurred, which helps you to determine which variables are null (but you could also use the debugger).

For the `MoviesControllerUnitTests` this probably is the `_mock` variable, so be sure to initialize it as shown in the [docs](https://github.com/moq/moq4), e.g.:

```
private Mock<MvcMovieContext> _mock = new Mock<MvcMovieContext>();
```

For the `HomeControllerUnitTests` you might need to mock the `Activity` or set a `HttpContext` (see e.g. this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400030/mock-httpcontext-for-unit-testing-a-net-core-mvc-controller0)).